# Adding a ResourceOwnerPassword client

Tags: identityserver4

I need to create a new client for a window app.  This app will create (via my own api) a Client in ID4.

Ive used the ConfigurationDbContext in my api to add clients.

When I try to authenticate the client using ResourceOwneerPassword I get an error:

```
IdentityServer4.AspNetIdentity.ResourceOwnerPasswordValidator | No user found matching username: ...
```

The documentation for ID4 says to use the Config class and GetClients() etc but only shows how this works for InMemory stores.  Im using EF Core.  Besides, these clients are added dynamically not statically at startup.

Is there no higher level service than the db context?  Do I have to figure out the db structure and add the data myself?  Seems very.... non intuitive :/

Comment: Did you check the EF sample with AspNetIdentity: https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4.Samples/tree/release/Quickstarts/Combined_AspNetIdentity_and_EntityFrameworkStorage

Comment: Thanks, I did miss that.  It helps.  I still think there could be some better documentation.  I wasnt planning on needing to be a security expert :)